# Kafka message Value conversion from Integer to String

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a kafka message in one kafka topic. One of the keys of this message `key=ID` and value of that key is `value=12345678910111213141`.

Type of this value is `integer`. I want to convert the type to `string`.

Currently am doing this in some hacky way:

- consume message
- convert the type
- produce the message to other topic

Is there an easier way to do this?

PS: Don't have the access to the first producer which sends the message as `integer`.

Comment: can you show the code ?

Comment: which part? my hacky way or something else? because I dont think that the way I'm doing that convertion is related. I just wonder if there is an easy way to change the type of the value of a kafka message key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this will not be possible. As far as Kafka is concerned, all data is stored as Bytes and Kafka does not know which Serializer was used to generate the byte code.

Therefore, you can only deserialize the value in the same way as it was serialized by the Producer. As I understand, this was done using a Integer Serializer. But as you do not have acces to the Producer, you have no chance but reading it as an Integer and converting it to a String afterwards.

Comment: yea I was afraid of that, that is the way I currently go around the problem. thx!